# Are Autowired fields accessible during class construction?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First, I'd like to address that this question does not relate to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null), which is about @Autowired fields being null due to the incorrect way to instanciate classes.

I have a few autowired fields in one of my classes. I also have another private field, header, that is used in most of my functions. So, to have a cleaner and more concise code, I wanted to fill header during class construction. The point is that, in order to fill header, I need to call functions that comes from an autowired instance.

This works fine:

```
public class Foo{

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someInstance;

    private HttpHeaders headers;

    private void init(){
        String value = someInstance.getValue();
        headers = this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("key", value);
    }

    public void SomeFunction(){
        init(); //i don't want to call init()
        //header has it's key set to value, working fine
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem right to me having the function `init()` to initialize headers. This is what constructors are for. So I want to do this:

```
public class Foo{

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someInstance;

    private HttpHeaders headers;

    public Foo(){
        String value = someInstance.getValue(); //someInstance is null, I get NPE
        headers = this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("key", value);
    }

    public void SomeFunction(){
        //header is null, since the constructor threw an exception
    }
}
```

As commented on the code above, in that case someInstance is null. Are Autowired fields accessible during class construction? I don't how spring treats the autowiring and class creation, but makes sense to me that this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, `@Autowired` annotation is handled by [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) which populates the corresponding fields after the object was created.

The most obvious solution for your problem is to use constructor injection.

```
 public Foo(SomeClass someInstance){
..
}
```

If you want to go with the init method, you can rely on Spring to call your init method after the bean was created/populated, this can be achieved by placing the `@PostConstruct` annotation on your init method.

Comment: Great answer. For me the @PostConstruct notation seems like a more elegant solution than passing constructor injection. Thanks a ton!